# Using $state.params in resolve does not work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently working on a small application that shows a 'drill down' type of menu. Unlike a TreeView my component only displays the current level.

There are only 3 levels: main, submenu, item. Drilling deeper (on the item) will result in a new state that corresponds to a detail view of the selected item.

I have only 2 states, the first is valid for any of the three levels. The second is the detail state:

```
 $stateProvider.state('menu', {
        url: '/menu/:submenu/:item',
        templateUrl: 'src/menu/views/menu.html',
        controller: 'MenuController',
        controllerAs: 'MenuController',
        resolve: {
            data: function($stateParams, MenuService){
                return MenuService.loadUri($stateParams);
            }
        }
    }).state('menu.details', {
        url: '/:selectedItem',
        templateUrl: 'src/menu/views/menu-details.html',
        controller: 'MenuDetailsController',
        controllerAs: 'MenuDetailsController',
        resolve: {
            data: function($stateParams, MenuService){
                return MenuService.loadUri($stateParams);
            }
        }
    });
```

This solutions works correctly, however I'm a bit annoyed by the fact I need to define the `resolve`method twice. I am required to do this as `$stateParams` contains only the params of that exact state (excluding child states) and I need all parameters to form a valid URL to fetch the corresponding resource via the `MenuService`.

I know that `state.params` can be used to get **all** state params, however it doesn't seem to work in the resolve method: it contains the parameters of the **previous** state.

Does anybody know how I could fix this? Having a child state that should simply trigger a new view, whilst using the resolve method of the parent state with all state parameters?

If you think I'm completely misunderstanding how states work, then please go ahead and tell me :)

Comment: Have you considered a simple loop through the state items? I've done that in the past to ensure that certain data was preloaded for each location.

Comment: @null would that be a loop over $stateParams or a loop over $state.params?

Comment: I meant create a route object, which contains all the states. Something like `{ 'menu': { /* ... */ }, 'menu.details': { /* ... */ } }`. Loop through the key values with an `angular.forEach`,  adding that `resolve: { data }` to each entry and calling `$stateProvider.state` in that some loop. I only have my phone right now, so sorry if this is abit cryptic.